# how to solve this error while egestion to neteza? count of bad input rows reached maxerrors limit

Tags: apache-spark, hive, netezza

i am trying to egest this table from hive to neteza
it gives me this error
it happened because of the special characters(non ascii)? how to find special characters in hive/csv file/ notepad ++?
just i want find non ascii characters

```
List of errors:
[Unable to write to NPS or read from HDFS. Broken pipe, Unable to write data to NPS: ERROR:  External Table : count of bad input rows reached maxerrors limit, ]
[Unable to write data to NPS: ERROR:  External Table : count of bad input rows reached maxerrors limit, ]
[Cannot connect to NPS: Connection refused. Check that the host name and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.]

com.ibm.nz.fq.common.exception.QArchException: Exporting the data failed.
List of errors:
[Unable to write to NPS or read from HDFS. Broken pipe, Unable to write data to NPS: ERROR:  External Table : count of bad input rows reached maxerrors limit, ]
[Unable to write data to NPS: ERROR:  External Table : count of bad input rows reached maxerrors limit, ]
[Cannot connect to NPS: Connection refused. Check that the host name and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.]

      at com.ibm.nz.fq.transfer.plain.PlainDataTransferService.transferDataToWarehouse(PlainDataTransferService.java:364)
      at com.ibm.nz.fq.ArchiveManager.transferDataWithConvertion(ArchiveManager.java:729)
      at com.ibm.nz.fq.ArchiveManager.transferDataFromHadoop(ArchiveManager.java:522)
      at com.ibm.nz.fq.ArchiveManager.exportDataToWarehouse(ArchiveManager.java:433)
      at com.ibm.nz.fq.pda.ExportUtil.exportSingleTable(ExportUtil.java:413)
      at com.ibm.nz.fq.pda.ExportUtil.exportDataToWarehouse(ExportUtil.java:89)
      at com.ibm.nz.fq.NzTransfer.exportToWarehouse(NzTransfer.java:543)
      at com.ibm.nz.fq.NzTransfer$1.run(NzTransfer.java:280)
      at com.ibm.nz.fq.NzTransfer$1.run(NzTransfer.java:271)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
      at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
      at com.ibm.nz.fq.NzTransfer.run(NzTransfer.java:271)
      at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
      at com.ibm.nz.fq.NzTransfer.verifyAndRun(NzTransfer.java:223)
      at com.ibm.nz.fq.NzTransfer.main(NzTransfer.java:179)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
      at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:233)
      at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)
INFO : 06:19:18 Extraction failed
INFO : 06:19:18 Exiting Script
```